# Whatsapp Business verification code not received

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I'm having trouble receiving the verification code for my WhatsApp Business account. I'm following all the steps correctly and also checked the logs on the 'monitor' to see if anything arrived, but nothing.

[Twilio console verification code request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GKJ.png)

These logs only show messages from twilio whatsapp sandbox
[monitor logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av6yf.png)
[whatsapp business requesting code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6wnN.png)

I tried re-send verification code a multiple times, but still doesnt have received the code.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an ad-blocker or other browser extensions running that might block this? This could cause this behavior. I'd recommend trying this again while disabling all ad-blockers.

Comment: Hi @IObert, still not receiving the verification code, any other tip ?

Comment: I try to do the voicemail option but still dont work

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there are intermissions in the service, the email providers are known for having problems.
2. Put your phone in airplane mode on and off and try again.
3. The registered number may be wrong, check again.
4. Contact customer service if everything else fails.

Comment: Hey Arcadian thanks for your answer, but this number i buyed directly from twilio the message come from a SMS only already checked number and everything ok, do you now how i can check if the twilio services is down?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).